# How do I read a specific records from every csv file and merge in a same file?

Tags: python, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0YhN.png)

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/f57525e860010f6c5c0c103fd97e2e7282b480c8/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports

In JHU covid-19 dataset, I hope to get the death number of suffolk country. And add a new column "death" in the cdc vaccine dataframe(I plot in the picture). You can see that the covid data is in every day records. So how do I achieve it in python?

Comment: One step at a time.  If it were me, I'd write code to scan all the files in that repository, and create a new CSV that only has two columns: date, and number of deaths.  After that, merging into your original data should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

so first you want to get a list of the files

```
from glob import glob
files = [item for item in glob("directory_that_contains_csvs/*.csv)]
```

The next step is that you can the iterate over these files and concatenate them:

```
all_files = []
for file in files:
   df_file = pd.read_csv(file)
   all_files.append(df_file[df_file['column_name'] == 1])

df_all = pd.concat(all_files, axis=1)
```

And you should be good.

The process is that you:

1. Create a list of the files you want to load
2. Create a list that can be used to append all the dataframes
3. Use a for-loop to iterate over that list and append the loaded dataframe
4. Concatenate all the dataframes in the list to a single dataframe.

I hope this helps